# Ajax single out answers as you type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the AJAX example at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp to try and search through values as the user types.

I would like to make an change to this but Im not sure how I would do it.

What I want to do is, rather than highlight what the user is searching for, list ALL of the values and remove them if they are not the correct one.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried running the function when the user is not entering any input and also tried manipulating some of the javascript. I am having a lot of trouble understand the PHP code though.

Comment: Show us your code & we all would be glad to help!

Comment: My code at the moment is pretty much just the same as the code in the example so anything that could be added to that would most likely also work with mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display="none";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
```

But, I would advice you to use a jQuery plugin for live searching. Take a look at these examples:

http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/